# Many to many joins in Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I understand that EF 2.0 does not yet support many to many joins, so I have followed the helpful details in [Fluent API, many-to-many in Entity Framework Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184678/fluent-api-many-to-many-in-entity-framework-core-2-0) to query my database.

I have a table of Insights, and Topics, and the relevant join tables.  An insight can have multiple topics and a topic can have multiple insights:

```
public class Insight  
{
    public int InsightId { get; set; }     

    [Required]
    public string Heading { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InsightTopicJoin> InsightTopicJoins {get; set;}

}

public class InsightTopicJoin
{
    public int InsightId { get; set; }     
    public Insight Insight {get; set;}
    public int InsightTopicId { get; set; }     
    public InsightTopic InsightTopic {get; set;}

}

public class InsightTopic  
{
    public int InsightTopicId { get; set; }     

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InsightTopicJoin> InsightTopicJoins {get; set;}

}
```

My question is, how do I map the topic name as a subproperty to a DTO when querying for insights?

Currently when querying for insights by topic I use the following:

```
// InsightList is a DTO which I use to hide other properties (not shown here) when querying for data

public class InsightList
{
    public string Heading { get; set; }   
}

// This is my repository code which maps an Insight to an Insight DTO
if (TopicId == 0)
{
    return await _context.Insights
    .Select(p => new InsightList
    {
        Heading = p.Heading,
    })
    .ToListAsync();
 }
 else 
 {
     return await _context.InsightTopics
     .Where(p => p.InsightTopicId == TopicId)
         .SelectMany(p=>p.InsightTopicJoins)
         .Select(pc => pc.Insight)
         .Select(p => new InsightList
         {
             Heading = p.Heading,
         })
         .ToListAsync();
 }
```

I'd like to add the following property to InsightList:

```
public List<string> Topics { get; set;}
```

How do I change my query to get this data?

**Update:**

To be clear, currently my json result from my repository code looks like this:

```
{
    "heading": "Test Heading",
},
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
{
    "heading": "Test Heading",
    "topics": [
        "Topic 1",
        "Topic 2"
    ]
},
```

Comment: what is subproperty?

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify

Comment: you are avoiding to do it in two linq operations (first - fetch data, second -
 group it)?

Comment: I'm happy to do it in one operation, just don't know how to!

Comment: `Topics = p.InsightTopicsJoins.Select(itj => itj.InsightTopic.Name).ToList()`. I would also rename the class `InsightTopic` to `Topic` because right now it reads like it represents the join table since it has both `Insight` and `Topic` in its name. Then you will end up with: `Insight`, `Topic` and `InsightTopic` (no join needed) or call it `InsightToTopic`. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: That's great @CodingYoshi, worked perfectly, can you move this to an answer so I can accept it?  And you're right about the table names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
.Select(p => new InsightList
{
    Heading = p.Heading,
    Topics = p.InsightTopicsJoins.Select(itj => itj.InsightTopic.Name).ToList()
}
```

**Few Suggestions**

The class `InsightTopic` reads like a join table (bridge table etc) right now because it has both the words `Insight` and `Topic` in the name. I would name them like following:

```
Insight
Topic
InsightTopic // Or InsightToTopic (no need to mention Join in the name)
```

I would also rename the class `InsightList` to `InsightCollection` because the .NET framework follows this convention. If you have `List` in the name, it leaks the inner implementation of your class; `Collection` on the other hand could be any implementation such as an array, list, hashset etc.