# OData with Multiple tables joins in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, odata

I have worked with OData before from individual tables.

Example:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public String ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public List<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
}

[EnableQuery]
public class PeopleController : ODataController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(DemoDataSources.Instance.People.AsQueryable());
    }
}

http://domain/People?$select=Name

http://domain/People?$filter=Name eq 'Sam'
```

works fine

I want to use OData from multiple tables, my SQL will be fixed query with join conditions

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS productId,
    pd.name AS productName,
    pd.job_number AS serialNumber
FROM 
    tbl_product p 
JOIN
    tbl_productDetails pd ON p.id = pd.id
```

I have referred to the following resources before posting this question:

1. https://www.odata.org/odata-services
2. [AspNet Core WebApi OData - Many to Many join tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066076/aspnet-core-webapi-odata-many-to-many-join-tables)

I didn't find any solution, is it possible to apply OData in this situation?

I'm expecting OData to work same for filter, top, skip, select, order by as it works on single table for multiple tables with join conditions.