# How to add 2 Foreign Key on one database table using ASP.NET Core and Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

[image: Entities]

[image: College]

[image: Course]

[image: CollegeCourses]'

I have 2 database tables:

1. College
2. Course

Now I want to create an additional table for `CollegeCourses` but it should have also 2 foreign keys from `College` and `Course` table.

If I want one foreign key on a table then I can do like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().OwnsMany(f => f.CollegeCourses);
```

I'm not sure on what to do if I try to add two foreign keys in one table.

I tried this one but it didn't work, it creates another table instead of just `CollegeCourses`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<College>().OwnsMany(f => f.CollegeCourses);
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().OwnsMany(f => f.CollegeCourses);
```

**SOLVED:**
Thanks for the help guys!

I found this on the link provided by @Hassan:
[Fluent API, many-to-many in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184678/fluent-api-many-to-many-in-entity-framework-core)
[image: Sample Code]'

I'm a bit confused on why there are two foreign key as a primary key on a table. How do I get those data without an Id holding them?

And I created a sample based on the code above but the difference is that I added a variable Id as my primary key.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CollegeCourse>().HasKey(pc => new { pc.Id });

  modelBuilder.Entity<CollegeCourse>()
                .HasOne(pc => pc.College)
                .WithMany(p => p.CollegeCourses)
                .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.CollegeId);

  modelBuilder.Entity<CollegeCourse>()
                .HasOne(pc => pc.Course)
                .WithMany(c => c.CollegeCourses)
                .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.CourseId);
```

The database sample table look like this:
[image: Table]

Comment: Your `CollegeCourse` table needs to have two tables IDs, To have a better understating [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#basic-many-to-many)

Comment: @HassanMonjezi 

I just want my table to be something like this:

`create table CollegeCourses(
Id PK,
CollegeId FK,
CourseId FK)`

I check your link but I'm a bit confused. Sorry I'm just new to wed dev

Comment: Please include the actual code instead of images.

Comment: @GeraldFlores this thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184678/fluent-api-many-to-many-in-entity-framework-core

Comment: @HassanMonjezi, Bro! Thanks for the link. It works! On the link, the table only consist of two foreign key and all I did was add an Id as primary key and two foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You must change delete behavior of one foreign key to Restrict.
I create example:
First create your classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode1 { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode2 { get; set; }

    public City City1 { get; set; }
    public City City2 { get; set; }
}



public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers1 { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers2 { get; set; }
}
```

Next create **Mapped** class:

```
public class CustomerMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(k => k.Id);
        builder
            .HasOne(c => c.City1)
            .WithMany(c => c.Customers1);
        builder
            .HasOne(c => c.City2)
            .WithMany(c => c.Customers2).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

And for end `override OnModelCreating` method in `DbContext`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerMap());
}
```